# Writing NFC tags using a Nexus S

Tags: android, nfc, nexus-s

I have a **Gingerbread 2.3.4** powered **Nexus S** and I recently got some writable **NFC** tags. So far I can read them as blank tags, but I couldn't find a way to write data to them.
All my research has lead me to this article: [Writing tags with Nexus S](http://gibraltarsf.com/blog/?p=13) from January (*before 2.3.4 release*).

How do you write NFC tags inside your application, using your Nexus S? Any pointers?

Comment: I have written several using the free NFC Tagwriter app https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the Android NFC API text and dev guide a bit tricky to follow so a bit of example code might help here. This is actually a port of MIDP code I've been using in Nokia 6212 devices, so I probably haven't yet figured out everything about Android NFC API correctly, but at least this has worked for me.

First we create an NDEF record:

```
private NdefRecord createRecord() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String text       = "Hello, World!";
    String lang       = "en";
    byte[] textBytes  = text.getBytes();
    byte[] langBytes  = lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    int    langLength = langBytes.length;
    int    textLength = textBytes.length;
    byte[] payload    = new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];

    // set status byte (see NDEF spec for actual bits)
    payload[0] = (byte) langLength;

    // copy langbytes and textbytes into payload
    System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1,              langLength);
    System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1 + langLength, textLength);

    NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, 
                                       NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, 
                                       new byte[0], 
                                       payload);

    return record;
}
```

Then we write the record as an NDEF message:

```
private void write(Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {
    NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord() };
    NdefMessage  message = new NdefMessage(records);

    // Get an instance of Ndef for the tag.
    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);

    // Enable I/O
    ndef.connect();

    // Write the message
    ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);

    // Close the connection
    ndef.close();
}
```

To write to a tag, you obviously need the Tag object, which you can get from the Intent.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm a little late here, but I've written a [library](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/) for creating, reading and writing NDEF records you might find useful.

As you might have learned, the native Android NdefMessage and NdefRecord classes are only byte-array wrappers and so although the NDEF standard is quite well specified within the NFC forum standards, there is currently no proper high-level support in Android.

The project also includes read, write and beam template activities :-)

Answer (score 1):

NXP, the maker of many NFC compatible chips, makes a free but closed source app to manipulate NFC tags.  I've written quite a few tags with it.

See: NXP NFC Tagwriter app

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter

If you want to write code to do so, inazaruk's link helps, or you could try the O'Reilly "Programming Android" online book.  It's has an NFC section:

http://programming-android.labs.oreilly.com/ch16.html#ch18_id316624

It's not the greatest book -- I find it too dense and some parts are poorly written -- but its NFC section and code samples is the only one I've really seen to date apart from Android's own.

Comment: Just be aware that when writing tags with NXP seems to change the authentication on the tag so that they can then only be rewritten with this app.

Comment: And I was wondering why NXP SDK cannot write to a card after I wrote an NDEF message using NXP's own app. Isn't it weird or what?

Answer (score 0):

To write NDEF data you can use the Ndef.writeNdefMessage() API.

If you want to write non-NDEF data then you can use the low-level transceive API's such as NfcA.transceive(), NfcB.transceive(), or IsoDep.transceive(). You will need to have advanced knowledge of the tag you are communicating with and its command/responses. I don't recommend this.

NDEF is the standard data format and can be easily read back by Android and other NFC platforms.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html#writeNdefMessage(android.nfc.NdefMessage)

Answer (score 0):

NXP's tagwriter is a great application for writing tags.

My company, which has an application for encoding and managing tags in the cloud, recently held a workshop in Seattle walking developers through the process of reading and writing NFC tags in Android.

The blog posts for [reading](http://tapintonfc.blogspot.com/2012/07/nfc-workshop-series-how-to-read-nfc-tag.html) and [writing](http://tapintonfc.blogspot.com/2012/07/the-above-footage-from-our-nfc-workshop.html) NFC tags walk through code and have supporting video clips from the actual workshop.

Hope this helps some developers get started with NFC!

Comment: Are you by chance affiliated with the site you are linking to?