# Write, read and share tag NFC on Samsung Galaxy SII

Tags: android, nfc

I have two Samsung Galaxy SII NFC and I want test new technologies NFC.
In particular, I want to write a tag with a device and read the tags with each other.

I have done exactly that but don't works like in the video.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vpjg5SD0qM

I have two Samsung GT-I9100P and my Android's version is 2.3.6.
Can you help me?

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [NFC intro](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html) will help you and have also a look to the [API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/package-summary.html) of NFC. The [NFC Basics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html) may be also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to program the device or simply use it?

For the first case I suggest you to check links below:

[Writing NFC tags using a Nexus S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283393/writing-nfc-tags-using-a-nexus-s)
http://www.jessechen.net/blog/how-to-nfc-on-the-android-platform/

Otherwise download excellent NXP applications from Google Play.

STeN

Comment: sorry, I have not specified. I download NXP from Google Play but it don't work(NFC enabled by settings). 
Tags are not recognized from devices..Why?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the application behavior? What it means "Tags are not recognized from devices"? Is application reading the content and does not recognize the data or tag type or you touch the tag and nothing happens?

Comment: I touch the tag and nothing happens. 
Sorry but perhaps my english is not good. Now I'm trying to upgrade Android.

Comment: Are you sure that you try to scan NFC tags and not RFID tags?